# How does Wind Damage actually work?

Tags: combat, deadlands-classic, injury

The rules say that in combat, for every wound you take, you take 1D6 times wound in wind damage. That seems pretty silly or I'm doing it wrong. If people have an average of 12 wind for example, a single heavy wound could knock them unconscious if I roll high enough or roll up some sixes. It seems like you can only take most times 2 wounds before going unconscious.

Answer (score 5):

Yeah, that's how it works. You get shot more than a little bit? You're probably going to go into shock, get distracted trying to keep your blood inside your gut, faint, or otherwise be taken out of the fight (“Gettin’ Winded”, *Deadlands* core book, p. 103).

Don't get shot!

You're not wrong that it means you can take basically two or three wounds before being taken out of the fight. In Savage Worlds, the spiritual and mechanical successor of Deadlands Classic, this dynamic was simplified to directly representing PCs' health with three Wounds, and that's it before they're out of the fight.